# ibtool failed when compiling storyboard

Tags: xcode, macos, storyboard, xcode4.5

I just downloaded a project from a git repository on two different Macbooks. On the first, it runs without problem.

On the second Macbook shows me the following message:

```
Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/ibtool 
failed with exit code 255
```

When trying to compile the file `MainStoryboard.storyboard`.

When I click the MainStoryboard.storyboard on XCode, it crashes and doesn't open it.

On the other computer, everything works fine.

I tried the following things to fix this problem, without success:

1) Upgraded XCode from 4.5 to 4.5.2

2) Removed the project directory and cloned the repository again.

3) Deleted the contents of my project on `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData`

4) `purge`

Any ideas on how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost half year later I finally succeeded to discover what was causing this problem and fixed the bug.

Now, with XCode 4.6.3 it gives me another clue about the problem:

```
2013-06-28 18:15:32.606 Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool[7894:f07] CFPreferences: user home directory at file://localhost/Users/[myusername]/Library/Application%20Support/iPhone%20Simulator/User/ is unavailable. User domains will be volatile.Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/ibtool failed with exit code 255
```

After receiving this new message, I searched for this **User** folder inside "iPhone Simulator" and there were no folder named "User".

I created the "User" folder, did a clean and after this I was able to build the project again!

Comment: If you fixed the original bug, why didn't you share the solution?

Comment: The problem was the missing User folder inside iPhone Simulator as I said on this answer...

Answer (score 2):

Found this issue using XCode 5.

I've solved the issue, but it required a hard reset.

Some said it was because I installed XCode outside of the App Store, or because the simluator was buggy, or because XCode was pointing at the wrong version of the Simulator, or a resoruce was missing a target membership, or whatever.  I tried all of that.

I downloaded XCode from the App Store, re-installed the Simulators, and still no luck.  So I just rolled back my repository to an earlier date, and lost some work in the process.  Not much though, because I always commit little and often.

Since ever starting to use storyboards back in 2011, I have always committed little AND OFTEN.  Storyboards are fragile.

EDIT
After adding the new components back in, the problem re-surfaced.

I noticed that I put a static table view, within a UIViewController.  I was doing this before.

I was using a subclass of UITableViewController in code, but the storyboard scene, was a UIViewController.  I dragged out a UITableViewController instead, and moved the table view cells into that, and it solved the issue.

All thanks to missing error messages. Where have they all gone since XCode 5?

Answer (score 1):

Do a

`which ibtool`

At the command line on both Macs. Chances are they are different.

Before Xcode was bundled in a single .app bundle it would install command line tools in folders like /usr/local.

I would recommend you remove those local copies to avoid interference with Xcode's built in version, i.e. that it uses the old version. If you still want to be able to use ibtool from the command line, here's an explanation about xcrun: http://www.cocoanetics.com/2012/07/you-dont-need-the-xcode-command-line-tools/

Comment: Both machines returns `/usr/bin/ibtool` to `which ibtool`

Comment: try calling them with --version

Comment: `$ ibtool --version
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
 <key>com.apple.ibtool.version</key>
 <dict>
  <key>bundle-version</key>
  <string>1878</string>
  <key>short-bundle-version</key>
  <string>4.5.2</string>
 </dict>
</dict>
</plist>` (both)

Comment: I'm out of ideas then. File a Bug Report with Apple.

Comment: I filed a bug report some months ago, but nobody answered it. All other bugreports I made were answered and fixed.

Answer (score 1):

the fix for me in Xcode 6.4 was to ... restart my computer. sad, but true.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error.  It turned out I had miswired some of the outlets in the tableview cell.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if someone is still struggling with this error but today was my turn to confront it. I just solved it. This is the context:

I had a UITableViewCell with half of it cover by a simple UIVIEW. Inside this UIVIEW i had many other view (UILables, UITextField, etc etc)

Just where the UIVIEW ended (Again it covered the middle of the entire UITableViewCell) i placed an UIImageView. Half of the UIImageView covered the UIView and the other half was on the UITableView itself. In the Hierarchy the UIImageView was on the UITableVIewCell and not inside the UIView.

The problem was when i was applying autolayout i put a constraint between a view inside the UIView and the UIImageView that was outside of the UIVIEW.

When i run the app, the error came up. After half an hour deleting views and stuff i realized that the error was caused by that constraint. After deleting that constraint, the error was gone.

So bottom line, check your constraints! only "Connect" views with others that are inside the same superView.

Good luck!

Answer (score -3):

Try completely reinstalling Xcode. Seems like there's something wrong with ibtool that a reinstall is probably able to fix.

Comment: It wasn't listed in the original list?

Comment: javsmo did not mention reinstalling Xcode, so I don't know where you're getting that it's been done...?